# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When using `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0`, FirebaseInstanceIdService and getToken are deprecated(). I cant find any documentation for onNewToken() method.

What is the difference between `FirebaseMessagingService.onNewToken()` and having this code

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("newToken",newToken);}
 });` ?

Comment: `getInstanceId ()` Returns the `ID` and automatically generated token for  `Firebase` project.

Comment: yes, but is the token that I will get using `onNewToken()` the same when using `getInstanceId()`? Is it okay to use either (only one) method in getting the token? like only using `onNewToken()` then I will just store the token in sharedpreferences? thanks

Comment: You should definitely only use only or the other. So if you're writing new code, only use `onNewToken`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was confused because they still don't have the documentation for this. Thank you :)